# python send commands to interpreter from script and get result

Tags: python, flask, ipython

My goal is to create a webpage the uses python and flask. I would like to have the ability to enter some commands into this web page, submit them to flask which will execute the commands in a python interpreter. Flask will then retrieve the results and send them back to the web page for presentation.

How can this be done? I currently am able to execute unix shell commands but cannot for the life of me figure out how to send commands to a python interpreter and retrieve the results.

I guess I should have clarified the purpose. This is for an internal web application for the company that I work for. Only employees will be able to access it while on our network and only after proper authentication has been performed. The employees need a way to have an interactive shell with the particular machine that they are logged in to through their web browser.

SOLUTION:

I found a nice module name Pexpect that does exactly what I want. Thank you for all of your suggestions.

Comment: can you be more specific with your question. Is your problem how to get a flask server running or just running a command in python in general?

Comment: if it was the latter, then flask has nothing to do with it. Flask is just a backend server framework.

Comment: Do **not** ever do this!!! What is the purpose of this anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses flask and pexpect module to call python interpreter.

```
@app.route('/console')
def console(): 
    import pexpect
    child = pexpect.spawn('python')
    child.expect('\n>>>')
    child.sendline('import os')
    child.expect('\n>>>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can invoke python in the same way as you do a shell script and pass python code to it using the -c option.  See http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html

However, this is unbelievably insecure and I would not recommend doing it in a web app!

If you are set on this, read up on restricted execution in Python http://docs.python.org/2/library/restricted.html

Answer (score 0):

The Werkzeug debugger that is included with Flask can do this when there is an exception, so I think it should be fairly easy to base your solution on that code, or at least to learn how Werkzeug does it.

The debugger server side code is [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/tree/master/werkzeug/debug). The client side is [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/tree/master/werkzeug/debug/shared).

I hope you have a good reason to do this, you normally do not want random people to execute code on your server.